# Tetris remove completed line and shift all the remaining block

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For now the code i'm using is this one:

```
    self.board = numpy.delete(self.board, row, 0)
    new_row = [0 for _ in range(configuration.config["cols"])]
    self.board = numpy.vstack([new_row, self.board])
```

The code corretly remove the row(an index) in question from `self.board`(2d numpy array), then add a new empty row shifting every piece down one.
The problem is when a piece should fall more than one single row, like in this situation:
[image]
The yellow piece should go all the way to the bottom since the rest of his tetramino is gone with the row

And i have no idea on how i could implement something like this

Full example:

```
import numpy

if __name__ == '__main__':

    board = numpy.array([
        [6,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0],
        [6,6,1,1,2,5,5,5,1,2],
        [6,6,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]
    ])
    
    expected_result = numpy.array([
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [6,6,1,1,1,5,1,0,0,0]
    ])
    
    for y,row in enumerate(board):
        if not 0 in row:
            board = numpy.delete(board, y, 0)
            new_row = [0 for _ in range(10)]
            board = numpy.vstack([new_row, board])


    print(board)
    print("--------")
    print(expected_result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. For what it's worth, the way you have it currently is how the "real" Tetris works. Blocks are left floating.

If you want pieces to fall, how to you want it to work?

Only pieces on the row immediately above? This would leave strange voids in the field but would be achieved by comparing each element in the row with the row below, and if the row below contains a 0 in that place then replace it with the row above. You'd get behaviour like this: [image]

All pieces in rows above the break? This would make an interesting game that would snowball quickly, but would be very different from traditional Tetris (traditional 2nd, all falling 3rd). You would need to loop over all of the rows with the same logic as the single row until you don't find any more elements to move. [image]

If you want to try to reinvent the game you're going to come into some balancing issues - I get that this is a programming exersize but its worth considering that it will probably take more time to make the game playable with falling blocks as it will to work out how to make the blocks fall.

Comment: On your first image, doesn't the "real" tetris push down the yellow square and leave the green and blue piece untouched? Or does it just leave a single yellow square floating in the line?

Comment: The original version of Tetris (and subsequent official versions) do not do this, no. It is possible that some versions of the game (namely 3rd party "clones") behave like this, but like I mentioned I can't see a way to make it work without some weird side effects.

Comment: Oh... i though the official tetris worked like this :| Thanks mate, you really made my life way easier